# passport-local failing to log in (express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have an app that I want to use passport local strategy to log in but it seems to fail when it comes to logging in. I'm not having any issue with registration, a user is created with hash and salt values.

my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const UserSchema = new Schema({

    name: String,
    surname: String,
    phone: String,
    email: String,
    
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, { usernameField: 'email' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

my passport config in app.js:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
const User = require('./models/user');

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, User.authenticate()));

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

finally my log in route(i have a basic form posting to /log-in with an email and password input field):

```
router.post(
    '/log-in',
    passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/log-in' }),
    async (req, res) => {
        
    }
);
```

log in form:

```
<form action="/log-in" method="POST">
 <div class="mb-3">
   <label for="email" class="form-label">Email address</label>
   <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">

 </div>
 <div class="mb-3">
  <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" aria-describedby="passwordHelp">
 <div id="passwordHelp" class="form-text"> Please rememeber that passwords are case sensitive.</div>
 </div>
 <div class="d-grid gap-2"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Sign In</button></div>
</form>
```

registration form and route:

route:

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const staff = new User(req.body.user);

        const password = req.body.password;

        const registeredUser = await User.register(staff, password);

        res.redirect(`/staff/profile/${staff._id}`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
});
```

form:

```
   <form  action="/register" method="POST" class="row g-3 mt-5" >

     
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="name" class="form-label">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="user[name]">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="surname" class="form-label">Surname</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" name="user[surname]">
        </div>
<div class="col-6">
            <label for="phone" class="form-label">Contact Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="user[phone]">
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <label for="email" class="form-label">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="user[email]">
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
          </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show your registration method since I can't see a password in the model I assume you're not registering the user before trying to login

Comment: @MohamedOraby hi i have added the red method and the log in form as well

Answer (score 0):

I just realized what the issue was, I had no name="" field on my log in inputs. That was the problem.